# Lost connection to MySQL server during query [2013] in shiny app

Tags: mysql, r, shiny, rmariadb

I have migrated MySQL older version to v8.0.19 . In older version it worked fine, but now facing some issues with pool connection as below:

R SQL connection pool:

```
library(pool)
library(DBI)
library(RMariaDB)

pool = dbPool(
  drv=MariaDB(),
  dbname="mydb",
  username="root",
  password=Sys.getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD"),
  host="localhost",
  sslmode = 'require',
  port=3306
)
statement = paste0("select * from Employee where Id IN (", ids ,")")
con3 = poolCheckout(pool)
x = dbGetQuery(con3,statement) //Throwing Error here
poolReturn(con3)
```

But it is working when I changed same code to :

```
statement = paste0("select * from Employee where Id IN (", ids ,")")
con3 = poolCheckout(pool)
x = dbGetQuery(pool,statement) //Not getting any issue like this
poolReturn(con3)
```

Is it I am doing in wrong way?

Comment: lol, just because I am using future and promise packages in my application, its throwing the error. Ref: https://github.com/rstudio/pool/issues/83

Answer (score 0):

Whats going on there  (", ids ,")")?

x = dbGetQuery(con3,statement) not the same as below , you have pool there!

Comment: I am passing the  strings separated by commas.